# Бекап certbot ssl ключей и сертификатов для веб хоста

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, certbot

В наличии есть около 20 различных проектов, находящихся на разных хостингах и т.д. Есть один резервный сервер, на котором лежат все проекты, я хочу копировать с помощью rsync следующие директории letsencrypt: csr, key, live, archive.

В директориях csr и key лежат файлы с однотипными названиями, которые будут перезаписываться в случае копирования, но, как я понял(исходя из ответов админов в [этом вопросе](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/why-is-there-etc-letsencrypt-keys-directory/43812/5)), эти директории служат бекапом для ключей в archive(на которые ссылаются символические ссылки в live). Будет ли правильно просто копировать live и archive?

Comment: Я не увидел в собственной ссылке, в ответе модератора, на голосование за удаление этих директорий, так что, я думаю, их можно не копировать https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/4634

Comment: csr не используется никак, keys просто хранит копии privkey.pem (и тоже не используется никак)

Comment: Если интересуют только текущие ключи и сертификаты, можно вообще копировать только папку live с переходом по симлинкам (опция `-L`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are for backup purposes and I believe that we would nowadays be better off without them, as they’re extremely rarely used by users but often cause confusion.

We did originally think that it was helpful to have a backup copy of the relatively irreplaceable items in the certificate request (you can get the cert itself out of CT if necessary). But nowadays what we find that what people overwhelmingly do if they accidentally delete these items is just get a new certificate.

https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/4634